# R - filtering rows and summing

Tags: r, data.table

I have a `data.table` with multiple columns. I am trying to sum a subset of one particular column.

```
sum(basetable_orig[get(var) %in% values[s], .(get(target))])
```

However, that results in an error:

> Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : 
>     only defined on a data frame with all numeric variables

Therefore I looked into it and here is what I found so far:

```
var <- "colName"
target <- "target"
s <- 1
values <- c("1","2")
```

The column of interest is numeric type:

```
str(basetable_orig[,c("colName")])
#gives following:
Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  12345 obs. of  1 variable:
$ colName: num  1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

Neverthless, I saw that `data.table` automatically converts numeric variable to factor:

```
tst <- basetable_orig[get(var) %in% values[s], .(get(target))]
str(tst)
#gives following:
Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  12345 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ V1: Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

Therefore it clearly cannot do sum. Thus, can anyone explain to me please **why** is this happening and **how** to fix it?

**EDIT**

Below is a reproducible example.

```
var <- "colName"
target <- "colTarget"
s <- 1

example_data <- data.table(colName = c(1,2,1,2,1), colTarget = c("0","0","1","1","1"))
example_data <- example_data[, colTarget:=as.factor(colTarget)]
str(example_data)
#Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame': 5 obs. of  2 variables:
#  $ colName  : num  1 2 1 2 1
#$ colTarget: Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 1 2 2 2

values<-names(table(example_data[,get(var)],exclude = NULL))
print(values)
#[1] "1" "2"

tst <- example_data[get(var) %in% values[s], .(get(target))]
str(tst)
#Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame': 1 obs. of  1 variable:
#$ V1: Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 2 2

sum(example_data[get(var) %in% values[s], .(get(target))])
#Gives an error:
#Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : 
#  only defined on a data frame with all numeric variables
```

Expected output is following. This is the table I have and I want to calculate number of "1" in colTarget for colName=1. Thus, the result should be 2 (sum of rows 1,3,5 of column colTarget)

```
   colName colTarget
1:       1         0
2:       2         0
3:       1         1
4:       2         1
5:       1         1
```

Comment: Can you please provide a reproducible example along with the expected outcome?

Comment: what are you trying to sum? what is the output you want?

Comment: I added an explanation to the question - basically I want to see number of "1" in that selection.

Comment: you want to see the number 1 in what selection? your question is still unclear. can you please explicitly add expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
library(data.table)
example_data[colName == 1 & colTarget == 1, sum(colName)]
```